# Using interfaces in constructor functions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am starting to write my first little app in TypeScript. I am learning about interfaces and how can they be implemented in classes. But what if I wanted to use them in a constructor function?

Let's say I have an interface:

```
interface WebScraper {
  url: string,
  getRawContent(): string,
}
```

when I used classes I would simply code

```
class Scraper implements WebScraper {
  //...
}
```

but how do I do it for a constructor function? I will be using it with the `new` keyword so it will return an object with specific properties. Would that be correct then, if I specify the interface as the return type?

```
function Scraper(): WebScraper {
  //...
}
```

I actually tried that and got an error

> error TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

How do I solve this then?

Comment: "*how bad and fake they are in JavaScript*"?? classes are not bad and are hardly fake. They are syntactic sugar over prototypes, sure, but "bad"? On what grounds?

Comment: typescript is actually syntactic sugar over javascript too! javascript + type checkings; the code essentially transpiles down to javascript before it works!

Comment: So...it's bad because if you don't know what it does, the presence of `class` will make you...not know what the classes do. Basically, it's only a problem if it's a problem?

Answer (score 1):

This syntax was explicitly declined, per [issue #2310](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2310). Syntax from the declined proposal:

```js
interface FooInstance {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}
interface FooConstructor {
    new (x: number, y: number): FooInstance;
}
// this an error, new(x,y)=>FooInstance is not assignable to (x,y)=>void
var Foo: FooConstructor = function (x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
var foo = new Foo(1,2);
```

[A comment in issue #2299](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2299#issuecomment-78393037) (the issue that spawned #2310) has a workaround. Adapted for your case:

```
interface WebScraper {
    url: string,
    getRawContent(): string,
}

interface WebScraperConstructor {
    new(): WebScraper;
}

const MyScraper: WebScraperConstructor =
        <WebScraperConstructor><Function>function (this: WebScraper) {
    this.url = '';
    this.getRawContent = () => '';
}

let myScraper: WebScraper = new MyScraper();
```

Note that this workaround does *not* keep type safety, via the cast to Function, but is safe enough to treat your arbitrary constructor method as a newable function that returns your choice of value. All that said, this syntax is decidedly hacky, per RyanCavanaugh in #2310.

> If anything we'd rather remove the ability to `new` `void` functions. The inconsistency is unfortunate but we didn't want to add a large type safety hole for the sake of consistency with a facet we don't even like in the first place.

It's probably worthwhile to let TypeScript guarantee your WebScraper return value is well-formed—with all properties set according to the interface—by properly defining it through a JavaScript/TypeScript `class`.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because `Scraper()` doesn't return an object that implements the `WebScraper` interface. The following compiles just fine:

```
interface WebScraper {
  url: string,
  getRawContent(): string,
}

function Scraper(): WebScraper {
    return {
        url: "foobar",
        getRawContent: () => ""
    }
}
```

As does this:

```
interface WebScraper {
  url: string,
  getRawContent(): string,
}

class Scraper {
    url = "foobar";
    getRawContent() {
        return "content";
    }
}

function ScraperFactory(): WebScraper {
    return new Scraper();
}
```

Edit: Based on the comment, you want:

```
interface WebScraper {
  url: string;
  getRawContent(): string;
}

function Scraper(args : WebScraper): void {
  this.url = args.url;
  this.getRawContent = args.getRawContent;
}

const scraper: WebScraper = new Scraper({url: "foo", getRawContent: () => "bar"});
```

It's worth noting that Typescript can't infer the return type of `new Scraper`, since `new` [just creates a new `any` object and passes it to Scraper as `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new). `Scraper` operates on `this`, it doesn't return anything. This is why you would use classes - Typescript would be able to infer what the desired shape of the returned object should be.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense, but my intention was not to return an object from a function but rather use it as a constructor it with `new` keyword. is it possible?